# Java.lang.Double cannot be cast to abi 47_0_0.com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableMap

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I updated my project to 47 expo version. Also, i fixed ViewPropTypes error using bable-plugin-module-resolver. It works good, but when i'm trying to use react-native-qr-svg or expo-barcode i get this error. [error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENcEu.jpg).
I tried to install different react-native-svg versions, but it doesn't help.

My package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@hmscore/react-native-hms-location": "^6.4.0-300",
    "@hmscore/react-native-hms-map": "^6.3.1-304",
    "@hmscore/react-native-hms-push": "^6.3.0-304",
    "@hmscore/react-native-hms-safetydetect": "^5.2.0-300",
    "@microsoft/applicationinsights-react-native": "^3.0.0",
    "@microsoft/applicationinsights-web": "^2.8.8",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "6.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "9.3.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.2.0",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.3.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.8",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.5.0",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.1.1",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.3",
    "appcenter": "^4.4.5",
    "appcenter-analytics": "^4.4.5",
    "appcenter-crashes": "^4.4.5",
    "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^3.0.1",
    "expo": "^47.0.0",
    "expo-application": "~4.2.2",
    "expo-barcode-scanner": "~11.4.0",
    "expo-blur": "~11.2.0",
    "expo-cached-image": "^44.1.7",
    "expo-cli": "^6.0.8",
    "expo-clipboard": "~3.1.0",
    "expo-constants": "~13.2.4",
    "expo-dev-client": "~1.3.1",
    "expo-device": "~4.3.0",
    "expo-file-system": "~14.1.0",
    "expo-haptics": "~11.3.0",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "~10.4.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~13.3.1",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~11.4.0",
    "expo-local-authentication": "~12.3.0",
    "expo-localization": "~13.1.0",
    "expo-location": "~14.3.0",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.16.1",
    "expo-secure-store": "~11.3.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.16.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
    "expo-storage": "^44.0.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.14.7",
    "global": "^4.4.0",
    "libphonenumber-js": "^1.9.49",
    "lottie-react-native": "5.1.3",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.5",
    "react-native-awesome-alerts": "^1.5.2",
    "react-native-barcode-expo": "bloodymonkey/react-native-barcode-builder-expo",
    "react-native-country-picker-modal": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "^10.3.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-flash-message": "^0.2.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.5.0",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "~1.8.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-map-clustering": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-maps": "0.31.1",
    "react-native-modalize": "^2.0.13",
    "react-native-password-strength-meter": "bloodymonkey/react-native-password-strength-meter",
    "react-native-portalize": "^1.0.7",
    "react-native-qrcode-svg": "^6.1.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.9.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.3.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.15.0",
    "react-native-sms-retriever": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.7",
    "react-native-webview": "11.23.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "shorthash": "^0.0.2",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.4.1",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "validator": "^13.7.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem with the expo version, I downgraded to "expo": "~45.0.0", and "react-native": "0.68.2" or "expo": "~46.0.0",and "react-native": "0.69.6".

Just change those in your package.json file then

1. Delete node_modules
2. Delete package-lock.json
3. run `expo install`
4. run `expo start -c`

Comment: It works good with 45 sdk, but with 46 i get crash instead of that error.